# Como precarregar imagens de forma eficiente em javascript?

Tags: javascript, load

Queria saber se existe alguma funcao, alguma biblioteca ou qualquer coisa que facilite o precarregamento de imagens. O requirejs serve pra isso? Eu estou fazendo assim no momento:

```
var imgs = [];
imgs["cartas"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["ouros"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["espadas"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["copas"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["paus"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["versos"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["versos"]["azul"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["versos"]["verde"] = [];
imgs["cartas"]["versos"]["vermelho"] = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    imgs["cartas"]["ouros"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/ouros/carta${i}.png`));
    imgs["cartas"]["espadas"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/espadas/carta${i}.png`));
    imgs["cartas"]["copas"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/copas/carta${i}.png`));
    imgs["cartas"]["paus"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/paus/carta${i}.png`));
    if (i > 0 && i < 6) {
        imgs["cartas"]["versos"]["azul"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/versos/azul${i}.png`));
        imgs["cartas"]["versos"]["verde"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/versos/verde${i}.png`));
        imgs["cartas"]["versos"]["vermelho"].push(loadImg(`img/cartas/versos/vermelho${i}.png`));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Andei dando uma pesquisada e vi que não há nenhuma funcao magica pra carregar imagens em javascript o que fiz foi apenas isso:

```
var imgs = [];
imgs["versos"] = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    imgs[`ouros${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/ouros/carta${i}.png`;
    imgs[`espadas${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/espadas/carta${i}.png`;
    imgs[`copas${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/copas/carta${i}.png`;
    imgs[`paus${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/paus/carta${i}.png`;
    if (i > 0 && i < 6) {
        imgs["versos"][`azul${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/versos/azul${i}.png`;
        imgs["versos"][`verde${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/versos/verde${i}.png`;
        imgs["versos"][`vermelho${i}`] = (new Image()).src = `img/cartas/versos/vermelho${i}.png`;
    }
}
```

Já melhorou um pouco.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tens uma simples função para pre-carregares as tuas imagens

sempre gostei deste caso em particular é simples.

Todas as tuas imagens serão guardadas no *array* `images`.

```
var images = [];
function preload() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}

// exemplo como usar
preload(
    "http://meusite.com/img/001.jpg",
    "http://meusite.com/img/002.jpg",
    "http://meusite.com/img/003.jpg"
)
```

**[Saber mais](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)**